# Handling a button that opens a new tab and redirects you to it

Tags: selenium

After clicking the create invoice button, it opens a new tab and redirects you to it. Next, it should click a button but it says no element exists. Did it search the element on the current page ? not on the new tab?

Tried explicit wait for that button and tried switching back and forth to the tab

```
@Test (priority=3)
public void ProductListExpress() {
    driver.findElement(By.className("bttn-imp-create")).click();
    System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to Purchase.php");

    String newUrl1 = driver.getCurrentUrl();

    if(newUrl1.equalsIgnoreCase("http://localhost:82/purchase.php")){
        System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to Purchase page ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Failed in proceeding to Purchase page");
    }
}

 @Test (priority=4)
public void ClickInvoice() {




 }
 @Test (priority=5)
 public void test() {


        //Click create invoice button   
    driver.findElement(By.name("btncreateinvoice")).click();
    System.out.println("Successful in clicking create invoice");


 }
```

Expect to click button after redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all wait for 2nd window to open and be available to the WebDriver. You can use [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) for this like:

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
   ```

   Check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more information on the concept
2. Once you have the confidence that the number of windows is 2 you can use [switchTo().window()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#window-java.lang.String-) function to change the context for the 2nd window:

   ```
   driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().stream().reduce((f, s) -> s).orElse(null));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking on new button, new tab is getting open. In this scenario, you need to use WindowsHandles. Try below code:

```
@Test (priority=3)
public void ProductListExpress() {
driver.findElement(By.className("bttn-imp-create")).click();
System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to Purchase.php");

Set<String> winHandles= driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = winHandles.iterator();

    String parentWindowId = it.next();

    String newWindowID= it.next();//Here you will get windows id of newly opened tab
    driver.switchTo().window(newWindowID); //now your driver is switching to new tab

    String newUrl1 = driver.getCurrentURL();

   if(newUrl1.equalsIgnoreCase("http://localhost:82/purchase.php")){
    System.out.println("Successful in proceeding to Purchase page ");
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("Failed in proceeding to Purchase page");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to new tab with this way :

```
//Click create invoice button   
driver.findElement(By.name("btncreateinvoice")).click();
System.out.println("Successful in clicking create invoice");

ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

during execution whenever a new tab or window opens, control of the driver still remains in the original tab or window unless we write couple of lines of code to manually switch the control to new tab or window. 
In your case, Since the driver control is still in original tab and next element to click is in new tab, selenium is not able to find it, hence it says no element exists

```
@Test (priority=5)
 public void test() {
WebDriverWait w= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(x.get(1)); // here x.get(1) indicates that 
driver control is switched to new tab or new window
w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable("locator of button to be clicked"));
}
```

In case ,in your next steps if you can to continue execution in the original window or tab, you have to again switch selenium driver control back .

```
driver.switchTo().window(x.get(0));// during next steps if you want 
driver control to switch back to original tab or window you have to write this line 
   of code
```

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this is what you're asking, but it might be.  I was CTRL+CLICKING a button to open a new tab.  This is how I found the tab:

```
Set<String> curWindows = new HashSet<> (driver.getWindowHandles ());
String  newWindowHandle = null;
a.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).click(THE_BUTTON).keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();
this.delay (500);
for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles ()) {
    if (curWindows.contains (windowHandle) == false) {
        newWindowHandle = windowHandle;
        break;
    }
}

if (newWindowHandle == null) {
    log.error ("Unable to find the new window handle.");
    return null;
}
```